# Complex analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Question says show that $F(z)= x^{2}y^{2}$ is differentiable at all points on each coordinate axis, but is still nowhere analytic. In my solution, it is not differentiable anywhere except zero. Is it correct? Thanks.

Comment: What complex analytic function? I only see a real function of two variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $u(x,y)=x^2y^2$, then $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=2xy^2$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=2x^2y$. So, you get the Cauchy-Riemann equations$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}2xy^2=0\\2x^2y=0\end{array}\right.$$and, yes, the solutions of this system of equations are the points of the coordinate axis. So, your solution is *not* correct.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. I got it.